# Active Directory Delegation, specific attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to delegate control of specific OU to admin group for those attributes:

```
 msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress
 ProxyAddresses
 msRTCSIP-Line
```

However, this attributes are NOT listen in Active Directory Delegation Wizard.

[image]

I tried to find another way to do that with Powershell [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/archive/blogs/joec/active-directory-delegation-via-powershell). But i can't figure out how to set or pass those attributes in the command line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're at the wrong stage in the wizard - it's currently asking you for the _object type_, not the _attribute type_. If, for example, you're delegating update privileges for those attributes on all _user objects_ in a subtree, this is the step where you'd select `User`

Comment: Such a simple answer with a big sokution. Thanks sir.